# Map Reduce with HIVE

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, hive, reduce

I have 4 different Data Sets in the form of 4 CSV files and the common field among those is ID. I have to implement using Join . For implementing this concept which would be better Map Reduce or HIVE and is it possible combine both Map Reduce and HIVE

Many Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive translates Hive queries into a series of MapReduce jobs to emulate  query's behaviour. While Hive is very useful, it is not always efficient to represent your business logic as a Hive query.

If you are fine with **delay in performance & large data sets to join**, you can go for HIVE.

If your data sets are small, you can still use **Map Reduce Joins** Or **Distributed Cache**.

Have a look at [Map Reduce Joins](http://codingjunkie.net/mapreduce-reduce-joins/) article.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times `Map Reduce` will give better performance and control compared to `Hive` for any of the usecase. The code has to be written with better understanding of the usecase.

Yes, it is possible to combine both `Map Reduce` and `Hive`.